# Undefined function or method 'fitensemble' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am trying to use the method `fitensemble`in MATLAB R2009b in the following way:

```
ens = fitensemble(traini,traino,'AdaBoostM2',100,'Tree')

traini: 96 * 31 general

traino: 96 * 1  general
```

I want to do a classification into 96 classes and get the error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'fitensemble' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I couldn't find out where is the problem. I will appreciate if somebody could help me in this regards.

Thanks in advance, Gilnaz.

Comment: Is the statistics toolbox available and installed? Try `which fitensemble`, does it return a path?

Comment: are `traini` and `traino` cell arrays or matrices? Try `cell2mat`

Comment: Dear @Daniel thanks for your valuable reply.  
statistics toolbox is installed but no sign of `fitensemble`, unfortunately. I tried `which fitensemble` and the `fitensemble not found.` showed up in return. any suggestion to be able to add it to my statistic toolbox?

Comment: `fitensemble` is not available in your Matlab version, it was added later. Using the archived documentation (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/doc-archives.html) one could check when it was added, I don't have access to this documentation because I own a student license.

Comment: @Daniel, I have no access since I'm not a licensed user. BTW thank you very much.